# change contenteditable value with js

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the value of an input field from like this

```
<input type="text" id="prezzo-da-e" name="prezzo-da-e" placeholder="Prezzo (da €)" value="" class="advanced_select form-control">
    <div pseudo="placeholder">Prezzo (da €)</div>
    <div contenteditable="plaintext-only"></div>
</input>
```

to so:

```
<input type="text" id="prezzo-da-e" name="prezzo-da-e" placeholder="Prezzo (da €)" value="" class="advanced_select form-control">
    <div pseudo="placeholder">Prezzo (da €)</div>
    <div contenteditable="plaintext-only">1</div>
</input>
```

then adding "1" in the contenteditable div = "plaintext-only". The change I have to do through js.

i tried like this but it doesn't work

```
document.getElementById('prezzo-da-e').innerHTML = '<div contenteditable="plaintext-only">1</div>';
```

How could I solve?
Thanks

Comment: You can't put anything inside an input element. It's a [self-closing tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element). This is not valid markup and therefore the question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this :

```html
<input type="text" id="prezzo-da-e" name="prezzo-da-e" placeholder="Prezzo (da €)" value="" class="advanced_select form-control"/><br>
<label for="prezzo-da-e">Prezzo (da €)</label>
```

with the following javascript to edit the value :

```js
document.getElementById('prezzo-da-e').value = 'new value';
```